# Short papers in applied probability

Tags: pr.probability, journals

Which journals publish short papers/technical note in applied probability, for example stochastic approximation ?

Comment: Electronic communications in probability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the [Journal of Applied Probability](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=JPR).

Comment: The paper is not completely new idea, it is an extension/generalization of previously known result. Then among the two journals mentioned which one is better.